# RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Long neural network

Tags: python, pytorch

I know there are some questions that are like this question, but when I follow them it seems to lead me down a rabbit hole. As if The problem I just fixed causes another problem.

Here are 2 of the rabbit hole solutions I have kept because they have seemed to fix their problems. I doubt they would be of any help but here they are just in case.

one:

```
batch_X = batch_X.to(device=device, dtype=torch.int64)
batch_y = batch_y.to(device=device, dtype=torch.int64)
```

two:

```
 x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
```

This is the error I'm getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/14055/Desktop/Research/new 1.0.py", line 93, in <module>
    training()
  File "c:/Users/14055/Desktop/Research/new 1.0.py", line 63, in training
    output = model(batch_X)                              # passed input data here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  File "C:\Users\14055\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/14055/Desktop/Research/new 1.0.py", line 31, in forward
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
  File "C:\Users\14055\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 1051, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\14055\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\linear.py", line 96, in forward
    return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)
  File "C:\Users\14055\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\functional.py", line 1847, in linear
    return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Long
```

My code is below

```
import torch.cuda
import torch
import numpy as np
import sys
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchsummary import summary
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------
torch.cuda.set_device(0)
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
np.set_printoptions(threshold=sys.maxsize) 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------

input_data = torch.Tensor(np.load("inputData.npy", allow_pickle=True))
predict_data = torch.Tensor(np.load("predict.npy", allow_pickle=True))

input_data = input_data.type(torch.FloatTensor)
predict_data = predict_data.type(torch.FloatTensor)


print(type(input_data))

class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, gpu = True):
        super(NeuralNet, self ).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(248, 750).to(device)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(750, 10).to(device)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(x.size(0), -1)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x).to(device)
        return x.to(device)

def training():
    model.to(device)
    training.criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss() 
    optimizer= torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.003, weight_decay= 0.00005, momentum = .9, nesterov = True)   
    n_epochs = 20000  
    a = np.float64([9,9,9,9,9]) #antioverfit   
    testing_loss = 0.0

    BATCH_SIZE = 10
    EPOCHS = 3
    for epoch in range(EPOCHS):


        if(testing_loss <= a[4]): # part of anti overfit
            train_loss = 0.0        
            testing_loss = 0.0


            model.train()
            for i in (range(0, len(input_data), BATCH_SIZE)):
                batch_X = input_data[i:i+BATCH_SIZE]
                batch_y = predict_data[i:i+BATCH_SIZE]

                optimizer.zero_grad()

                batch_X = batch_X.to(device=device, dtype=torch.int64) #gpu                        # input data here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                batch_y = batch_y.to(device=device, dtype=torch.int64) #gpu                    # larget data here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

                output = model(batch_X)                              # passed input data here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                loss = training.criterion(output, batch_y)           
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
                train_loss += loss.item()*batch_X.size(0) 

            train_loss = train_loss/len(predict_data.train_loader.dataset)
            print('Epoch: {} \tTraining Loss: {:.6f}'.format(epoch+1, train_loss))


            model.eval()  # Gets Validation loss 
            train_loss = 0.0         
            with torch.no_grad():
                for i in (range(0, len(input_data), BATCH_SIZE)):
                    batch_X = input_data[i:i+BATCH_SIZE]
                    batch_y = predict_data[i:i+BATCH_SIZE] 

                    batch_X = batch_X.to(device=device, dtype=torch.int64)
                    batch_y = batch_y.to(device=device, dtype=torch.int64)
                    output = model(batch_X)
                    loss = training.criterion(output, batch_y).to(device=device, dtype=torch.int64)
                    testing_loss += loss.item()*batch_X.size(0)
            testing_loss = testing_loss / len(predict_data.test_loader.dataset)           
            print('Validation loss = ' , testing_loss)                      
            a = np.insert(a,0,testing_loss) # part of anti overfit         
            a = np.delete(a,5)           
    print('Validation loss = ' , testing_loss) 

model = NeuralNet().to(device=device)
#summary(model, input_size=(1, 248, 248))
training()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you cast X and Y to `int64`? Mainly, this is the problem.

```
batch_X = batch_X.to(device=device, dtype=torch.int64) #gpu                        # input data here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
batch_y = batch_y.to(device=device, dtype=torch.int64) #gpu
```

You cast `batch_X` and `batch_Y` to `int64` a.k.a `long`, but `float` was expected, hence the error. Replace this with

```
batch_X = batch_X.to(device=device) 
batch_y = batch_y.to(device=device, dtype=torch.int64)
```

or

```
batch_X = batch_X.to(device=device, dtype=torch.float) 
batch_y = batch_y.to(device=device, dtype=torch.int64)
```

And this should solve your problem.

EDIT: You only need to keep y as int. Since you are using CrossEntropyLoss which expects target labels (expected to be an int or long). Overall, you need to keep the data type of x to be float, and y should be long or int.

Comment: That was to fix another problem, When I change it back I get this.       

RuntimeError: Expected object of scalar type Long but got scalar type Float for argument #2 'target' in call to _thnn_nll_loss_forward

on line        

  File "c:/Users/14055/Desktop/Research/new 1.0.py", line 64, in training
    loss = training.criterion(output, batch_y)     Changing it to float also gives me this error.

Comment: See the edits, I did not realize earlier that you were using Cross Entropy.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem! Also if you don't mind where did you find this information? I couldn't seem to find it.

Comment: The error message says that the target should be `long` but we had cast it to `float`. That was my cue. Also, parameters of an NN are float, so input has to be float else matrix multiplication operations will throw errors. That was the earlier error message.